# Performance and memory differences between C# and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, performance, memory-management

We have a C# winforms application which models a 3D globe and world state using a large number of object instances, float[] arrays and object references to represent the world state and relationships between objects.

We have been asked to migrate this software to the web and reimplement it in Javascript.

I understand that C# gets jitted to native code, however it sounds as though in recent years there have been huge advances in Javascript performance too.

I am wondering if there is any general information or comparisons of how Javascript fares, performance and memory wise, for raw data manipulation of objects and arrays, compared to .NET or other languages which execute at native performance?

Comment: JavaScript has gotten very fast, the biggest problem is not the language but how people code their applications.    I recently listened to a talk where a Google engineer explained how they sometime use JS to implement JS features as they in some cases are faster than C++.  

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJPdhx5zTaw

A google search for JS vs native performance will give you a wealth of info. 

This library may be useful for the task at hand: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

I know you are looking for C# comparisons, but I think you may find this info equally helpful.

Comment: There exists a PHD dissertation paper re: compiled vs interpreted languages where interpreted are in theory faster.  It was some time ago and from a student at one of the California schools but unfortunately I did not keep the reference after I read the paper.  RE: c++ vs c# and JavaScript which are both interpreted one from IL and the other from text/script

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Short Answer

If you are a proficient C# developer and novice JavaScript developer - your C# will most certainly be faster. If you are proficient at both then your C# will probably be faster, but the difference may not be as much as you thought - this is all very program specific.

### Longer Answer

`C#` and `JavaScript` are languages so they don't have any particular performance characteristics themselves. `C#` compiles to .NET IL and is executed in a virtual machine, and various optimizations can be in play (such as the JITing you mentioned). `JavaScript` is not compiled, but rather interpreted - and is done so by the JavaScript engine particular to the browser. Each browser may have different approaches to improve "performance" of executing JavaScript - but performance optimization typically involves trade-offs (between speed and memory, for instance).

With everything else being equivalent (and non-trivial), the .NET code - JITed or not - will perform better than analogous JavaScript code running in a browser. The *degree* of difference in performance is highly specific to the particular program. Everything from the size and number of objects being processed down to how and when you use loops will affect how one runtime compares against the other.

### More Details

Developers are sometimes confused about which languages are interpreted or compiled, and many are under the impression that the two are exclusive. In reality the situation is a bit more complicated.

- C# for instance is compiled (into IL byte code). The IL Byte code is then interpreted (and typically JIT compiled by the particular .NET runtime).
- C# contains features such as `dynamic` and `Reflection.Emit()` which enable C# to be used more like a scripting language while also "circumventing" the compiler and  some of the performance benefits it provides.
- JavaScript is interpreted, but a JavaScript engine is completely free to JIT as it sees fit. Check this [blog article about Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/04/05/the-baseline-compiler-has-landed/) where they describe how they use a two-phase JIT approach.

In the "real world" (non-trivial code, standard compilers and standard settings) compiled code will run faster than equivalent "pure" interpreted code. However, nowadays interpreted code usually runs through a JIT compiler - which has the possibility to be faster than pre-compiled code (because the JITter could tailor compilation to take advantage of a particular instruction set, for instance). Languages  such as C# and Java take advantage of both compilation and "interpreted-JIT-compilation" by compiling down to byte code and then running through a JITer during execution.

The handicap that JavaScript faces in the performance arena has nothing to do with compilation but rather in certain aspects of the language and how it is (or tends to be) used. Again if you take a look at the blog entry on Firefox you see how changes to type information need to be tracked by the baseline compiler (which is better than the prior model of discarding the associated JIT  instructions entirely).

With all this taken into consideration, well written JavaScript on a modern browser will run extremely well. It will still suffer the performance hit of the initial JIT pass (the equivalent of compiling to byte code before the "real" JIT), but the engines are written to minimize this as much as possible.

Comment: On key here is that it is nearly impossible to reach the "everything else being equivalent" state here in this context

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - you are absolutely correct that the nature of the two environments makes it difficult or impossible to compare these  in an apples-to-apples manner. Nevertheless, it would be possible to construct programs in either language which would be considered "analogous" and compare performance in their own context. Under non-trivial examples of this approach, I propose one would find that C# would nearly always be faster - but the degree depends upon a large number of aspects of the programs themselves.

Comment: Ethan thanks for the detailed answer. It sounds like the only way to know in a specific instance is to prototype the code and compare.

Comment: "JIT compiler - which has the possibility to be faster than pre-compiled code (because the JITter could tailor compilation to take advantage of a particular instruction set" So? The compiled code has even more chances to take advantage of enhanced instruction sets.

Comment: JavaScript is a compiled language in most modern runtimes.